# Find all functions $f$ :- $\mathbb{N}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that :- $xf(y) + yf(x) = (x + y)f(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: analysis, functions, functional-equations

So here is the Question :-

Find all functions $f$ :- $\mathbb{N}$ $\to$ $\mathbb{N}$ such that :-
$$xf(y) + yf(x) = (x + y)f(x^2 + y^2)$$
I tried substituting values for $x$ and $y$, but I couldn't reach to a possible clue to the solution. Any hints or suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $N$? $\mathbb{N}$? If so, do you consider $0$ to be an element of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: N consists the set of natural numbers , 0 is not included .

Comment: Plugging in the first numbers gives $f(1)=f(2)=f(5)$. Every constant function is a solution. The question is if that's all; unless I'm wrong, we get by a kind of induction $f(m)=f(1)$ for all $m$ which are sums of two squares, and maybe on other $m$, $f(m)$ is arbitrary.

Comment: Okay , if you have an idea or so , can you just write it as a solution instead of a comment ?

Comment: Fair point. Done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose there exists an integer $n$ such that $f(1) <f(n)$. With $x=1$ and $y=n$, we have
$$
nf(1)+f(n) = (n+1)f(n^2+1) \implies f(1)<f(g(n))<f(n),$$
where $g(n)=n^2+1$. Repeating the same argument using $f(1)<f(g(n))$, we deduce that $$f(1)<f\left(g^{f(n)-f(1)}(n)\right)<f\left(g^{f(n)-f(1)-1}(n)\right)<\ldots<f(g(n)) <f(n),\tag{1}$$
where $g^m(\cdot)$ denotes the composition of the function $g$ repeated $m$ times.

However, there cannot be more than $f(n)-f(1)-1$ integers between $f(n)$ and $f(1)$. Thus, (1) leads to contradiction because $f(x)\in\mathbb{N},\forall x\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence, $f(1)\nless f(n).$

Using similar arguments, we can show that $f(1)\ngtr f(n)$. Therefore, we conclude that $f(x)=f(1)$ for all values of $x$ which trivially satisfies the given relation.

Answer (score 3):

Setting $x=y=1$ gives $f(1)=f(2)$. From there, try to show via induction that $f(1)=f(n)$ for all $n$ which are sums of two squares.

Remains the question if $f(n)$ can be defined arbitrarily on other $n$. For a counterexample, see comment by user Explorer (thanks!). I do not know if one can conclude further, and whether there are non-constant $f$ which satisfy the criterion.

EDIT: I realise what I had in mind here might not work. One only gets the following: If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $f(x^2+y^2)=f(x)$ as well, and starting with the above, one easily constructs infinitely many numbers $n$ with $f(n)=f(1)$. But to show that is true for *all* $n$, one needs more work, as in the other answer.

Comment: $f(n)$ cannot be arbitrary for other values of $n$. For example, with $x=y=5$, we get $$f(1)=f(5^2+5^2)=f(50)=f(7^2+1)=\frac{f(7)+7f(1)}{7+1}\implies f(7)=f(1).$$ However, $7$ can not be written as sum of two squares.